# does $_SESSION[] conflicts with defined class?

Tags: php

I called  a  class by:

```
$user = new user;
```

Then i defined  a session variable:

```
$_SESSION['user']= 'username';
```

in my script if  i echo  used `$_SESSION['user']` in some function it showed;

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class user could not be converted to string in /home/username/public_html/cart-admin/include/classes/class.auth.php
```

Comment: Are you running with [Register Globals](http://bg2.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) turned on?

Comment: Are you sure that's your code? It would make more sense if you had `$_SESSION[$user] = "username"`, it would fit the error more.

Comment: @vascowhite: The brackets may be omitted if there are no arguments for the constructor (Though I think it's still good practice to leave them here, plus To have the class name uppercased (`User`).

Comment: its exactly as i mentioned in question

Comment: @Truth: You means class name  must start with Uppercase letter?

Comment: @Truth yes, I'm just being pedantic.

Comment: @SharanHayer: It's a naming convention, it's supposed to help you as a developer to distinguish objects from functions (since they look the same).

Comment: @Truth Thanks. Please  explain possiblereason of error?

Comment: @SharanHayer: Is that code 100% the code you are using? It doesn't seem likely that this code would trigger the error you're seeing.

Comment: Sorry for asking this again .. but are you 100% sure (please, check it!) that your code is not like `$_SESSION['user'] = $user`? It's hard to believe that you hardcoded `$_SESSION['user'] = 'username'` in your script ;-)

Answer (score 1):

No, $_SESSION may never conflict with an object / instance of your `user` class.

Albeit your state that this is your actual code, it's hard to believe that you hardcoded `'username'` in your script. ;-)

Assuming your actual code looks like this:

```
$user = new user;
// ... many lines between ...
$_SESSION['user'] = $user;
// ... more lines between ...
echo $_SESSION['user'];
```

... then the error is easy to explain. When you do `echo $_SESSION['user']` PHP tries to implicitly convert the object referenced in this variable (an object of class `user`) into a string so it can be printed.

To check if i am right, you may insert this code right before your `echo`:

```
echo "session variable 'user' is of type: ", gettype($_SESSION['user']);
```

You will either see `.. is of type: user` which is what i expect, or you will see `.. is of type: string`, which is what you want.

There are two possible fixes for this:

1. either store the username property (instead of the object) inside the session. e.g: `$_SESSION['user'] = $user->getName();` or `$_SESSION['user'] = $user->name;`
2. use the magic [`__toString()` method (see manual)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) in your `user` class to make this implicit conversion possible. In `__toString()`, just return the username from inside the `user` object.

I'd go for option 1, which is more to the point and doesn't store a serialization of your user object in the session.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your script saves an object called `user` to the $_SESSION var. That's why you can't see the `username` string, it may be overwrited from the script. You have to use another keyword to store the username.

Comment: But `code`. $user = new user`code`.  and `code`. $_SESSION['user'];`code`.  are two different things. `code`. $user = new user`code`.  is a class and `code`. $_SESSION['user'];`code` is my defined variable.. It happens on older version of php. In newer versions it  doesn't happen

Comment: Do you use a third party script or framework? Does this script initializes a user object and sets it to the SESSION var ?

Comment: @SharanHayer, the older version of PHP has register globals turned on. Disable it.